# Count Unique User With Filter Combination

Tags: mysql

I have tables with millions of data. I need to create unique user based on msisdn column for all possible filter (area, region, branch, etc.) combination.
I count, there will 512 possible combination using 10 filters. I tried to do that, but the result have more record than the original data.

```
CREATE TABLE `REPORT_USER` (
    `trx_date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `msisdn` BIGINT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `area` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `region` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `branch` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `sub_branch` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `cluster` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `partner_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `adn_number` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `service_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    `service_type` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Unknown'
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Here is the query to select the data.

```
select  
trx_date as Date, 
area,  
region,  
branch,  
sub_branch,  
cluster,  
partner_name,  
service_name,  
service_type,  
adn_number,  
count(distinct(msisdn)) as User,  
 from REPORT_USER
 where trx_date >= '20171001' and trx_date <= '20171011' 
 and area is not null
 and region  is not null
 and branch is not null
 and sub_branch is not null
 and cluster is not null
 and partner_name  is not null
 and adn_number  is not null
 and service_name is not null
 and service_type is not null
 group by trx_date
```

if I increase the group by, the query time will increase.

What is the best method to count unique and using combination of these filters?

Comment: Why have you tagged this SQL Server?

Comment: edited, remove tag sql server

Comment: You want to create a user? You do something completyl different. Maybe select a user? Or do you really need to create unique ID for combinations of attributes (per msisdn)? Maybe you better describe what you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming that "increase the group by" means "increase the range date range in the `WHERE` clause"...)

That query cannot be sped up.  It must scan lots of data -- either the entire table (if your date range is 'large') or a significant chunk of the table (if the date range is 'small' *and* you have an index starting with trx_date).

Having no `PRIMARY KEY` is a bad idea.

Is this query the only one of importance?  Let's seek some others so we can discuss the optimal index(es).

Also, it is "wrong" to group by `trx_date`, yet fetch all those other columns.  The value for, say, `area` will be randomly picked for each `trx_date` -- a rather useless bit of info.